# Cylindrical dynamic object in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to make in Netlogo an object similar to this? [image]

I would like a dynamic object, formed by 3 circumferences and if possible, I wish I could dynamically resize them, making them larger or thinner.

Comment: You can create your own icons for agents and make an agent any size with its internal size variable, but that will change all of the rings proportionally. If just having the three rings is okay, there is no problem have three agents at the same location (of types N, Q and P) and having them of different colours and sizes so that you see different widths of each.

Comment: @JenB How can I do that?

Comment: @JenB At the moment, I am doing something with Turtle Shape Editor, but your approach is better and it is what a want. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Which approach - the icon that changes sizes or the three rings? Are the turtles static or do they move around?

Comment: @JenB The turtles don't move around. 
They should rapresent particular cells that could do the following things:
staying in a position;
dying (erase them);
generating another cell;
change they internal state (the 3 rings area).
The rings are always no more than 3.
What should I do to rapresent a similar system?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? They will have to be different agents, so you will have 3 times as many agents as you actually want.

```
to makecell
  create-turtles 1
  [ set shape "circle"
    set color green
    set size 20
  ]
  create-turtles 1
  [ set shape "circle"
    set color red
    set size 15
  ]
  create-turtles 1
  [ set shape "circle"
    set color gray
    set size 10
  ]
end
```

Comment: That perfectly works for one big cell:
how can I do that for a lot of small cells?
Do I need something like breed [ cells cell ] to store the properties of each cell (so I can change theese value later)?

Comment: That's actually really difficult to answer without a better understanding of your goal and also what each ring actually means. You might need three breeds, one for each ring. Could otherwise have single breed with a variable for type. But if there's lots of little ones, I can't work out how you will see that there are different width rings anyway. So you might be better off simply using shading to indicate critical conditions (eg turn red if too much out of balance).

Comment: I would like to be able to use each of the 3 rings as a unique object.
For example: I have 10 cells, each of them formed by 3 rings.
I would like to change the size of 1 ring of 5 cells and make the others 2 rings of theese cells to automatically resize.

Comment: Automatically resize to what size? Is there some formula that links the sizes of the three rings?

Comment: In your code for example, the cell size is 20 (the green ring's size, that is the external ring).
If the red ring becomes bigger, the green has to become smaller (but always external)

Comment: Do you have some free time today/tomorrow...? Can we chat for a while?